# Load Testing for gwt web application, gwt-rpc

Tags: java, gwt, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am looking for **open source automated testing tool** for load testing of GWT application.
Till now , I tried using jmeter for load testing but its plugin dependent and i havent got the plugin. There I am encountering some error.Another one i tried was Neoload it was asking for rpc files whuich i don't know how to find.Finally I just want some easy user friendly automated tool for load testing of gwt web application and gwt-rpc.

Comment: Neoload asking for rpc? rpc files are located where you build the application.check your build path location.

Comment: Sir, You have used neoload. Can u plz help me in it. I just did that much that i recorded the scenario of my web sites. It created binary files I suppose. But after stopping the recording it asked me for the gwt Missing libraries such as war file,rpc file and jar file.

Comment: @priya - You should go with - http://blazemeter.com/. It is really nice and efficient tool for load testing. It is also allow to run jmeter script using cloud.

Comment: but for gwt it need a ubik load pack plugin. Which i haven't received.

Comment: Why you need that plugin?

Comment: Actually i have to load test gwt-rpc of my project. So, i just studied that it needed a plugin.

Comment: http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-gwt-rpc-applications-with-ubik-load-pack-plugin-for-jmeter/